# Show winning success rate based on wins/loses count

Tags: php

I want to show the winning success rate between wins and loses I had a go with this

```
$percent = ($row['wins'] - $row['loses'] / (($row['wins'] + $row['loses']/2))* 100);
```

based on [calculatorsoup.com](http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/algebra/percentagedifference.php) % difference calculator formula

> Calculate percentage difference between V1 = 15 and V2 = 6
>
> ( | V1 - V2 | / ((V1 + V2)/2) ) * 100
>
> = ( | 15 - 6 | / ((15 + 6)/2) ) * 100
>
> = ( | 9 | / (21/2) ) * 100
>
> = ( 9 / 10.5 ) * 100
>
> = 0.857143 * 100
>
> = 85.7143% difference

but I think I'm going about it the completely wrong way, my goal is so output would be something like:

> user bob has a success rate of: 17%

Comment: wins / total_games where total_games = wins + losses

Comment: The "% difference calculator formula" is for things like "user bob is 15% more likely to win than lose".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the ratio *number of wins* / *total tries*:

```
$percent = 100 * $row['wins'] / ($row['wins'] + $row['loses']);
```

Comment: The thinking is correct, but there's no need to divide $row['loses'] by 2:
`$percent = ($wins/($wins+loses)) * 100`

Comment: @froddd Holy cow! You are right, I forgot to remove it when I edited the OP's formula.

Answer (score 0):

```
$v1 = $row[wins];
$v2 = $row[loses];

$percent = ( abs($v1 - $v2) / (($v1 + $v2)/2) ) * 100;
```

Comment: Lets say $v1=9 , $v2=3 , then your formula outputs `( (6) / (12/2) ) *100 = 100` . Can you please explain this output?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the success rate of a player this will be the code snippet:

```
$wins = 9;
$losses=3;
$succesRate =  ( $wins/ ($wins + $losses) ) * 100 ; 
//output will be "Success rate is: 75%"
echo "Success rate is:".$successrate."%" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

the math is quite simple if i understood the question:
W = wins

L = loses

T = W+L

the winning rate  in a proportion is W : T = X : 100.

in code

```
$w = $row['wins'];
$l = $row['loses'];
$rate = ($w * 100)/($w + $l)
```